# Network load balancer with Target group having targets inside Private VPC configuration not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb, elastic-load-balancer

I am having VPC with four subnets out of which 2 are private and 2 are public subnets.I have created Network load balancer into 2 public subnets present in different availability zones.I have also created target group to have target EC2 instances in private subnets.

I have whitelisted the primary private IP's of loadbalancer node's subnets as mentioned in documentation.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/target-group-register-targets.html#target-security-groups

The health check calls works fine with those instances marked as 'Healthy'. But the NLB endpoint is not accessible for TCP communication to outside world.
But when I whitelist EC2 instance to allowed access to all(`0.0.0.0/0`) for particular TCP port,then I am able to access that NLB outside of VPC.
Am I misconfiguring EC2 access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public Network Load Balancers balance traffic by modifying the behavior of the Internet Gateway... or, at least, that is how it appears from the user perspective.

The documented need to allow traffic from the load balancer's private IP is solely for the purpose of allowing health checker access -- health check requests appear to be coming from the address of the balancer.

All other traffic appears to come from the actual IP address of the client.  Any client address that needs to connect to the instances via the balancer needs to be allowed in the security group of the instance.

Comment: I was confused to the concept of Classic load balancer.So instance behind netwok loadbalncer get traffic as it is coming from client not the load balancer.

Comment: Correct, that's why it's called a *network* load balancer... it operates at the OSI "network" layer -- layer 3 -- manipulating the addresses on packets directly, rather than creating sockets in each direction and tying the payload streams together at one of the higher layers.